# Eloquent query but only with some attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a lot of users in my DB and there are a lot of user attributes and I think my query is slow because of that.

Is there a way to make a query with eloquent to get all users but only some of their attributes? Now I have a classic one:

```
$users = User::all();
```

And I want to get only username, created_at, active. So if I make a blade @foreach ($users as $user) loop and try to get $user->email this should give me an error because i don't need that field.

How to make such a query?

Comment: The `pluck()` method is what you are looking for: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$users = User::select('username', 'created_at', 'active')->all();`

Comment: i need to check that one. and is there a way to call select dynamically on a variable? like this `$agent->users->select()` that one doesn't work btw, the one in this comment

Comment: Assuming `users` is a relationship off `agent` then you would do `$agent->users()->select(['a', 'b', 'c'])`